# Looking for Java Regular expression to match last 2 digits in the given range

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a java regular expression to match last 2 digits of a 12 digit number to a range of digits.

So for example I want to match the given 12-digit number whose last 2 digits falls in the range of  (00-24) or (25-49) or (50-74) or (75-99).

I tried this: `5959.*[00-24]`, but it does not work and I can see this is not a correct regex. But I am not sure how to divide it into ranges.

Can someone please help?

Comment: So basically, it should be from `00-99`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex for checking if last 2 digits are `00-24`:

```
5959.*?(?:0\d|1\d|2[0-4])
```

Comment: Thanks , that worked. Can you tell me what   *?(?:   means , rest everything i understand .

Comment: Can you tell me what *?(?: means , rest everything i understand

Comment: `.*?` is same as `.*` except that `?` makes it non-greedy match. `(?:..)` is non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a misuse of regex that will only increase your maintenance and development costs. This would be much better expressed in good old-fashioned code. Just extract the number of interest (with regex), parse it as an integer, then test value is within the desired range.

```
String input = "012345678909";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{10})(\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    boolean valid = value <= 24;
}
```